# Удаление строки из текстового файла в дизайнере форм

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

У меня есть текстовый файл с номерами телефонов и ФИО их владельцев, они записаны в одну строку. Как можно удалить определенную строку? Я думал сделать это как то через тот же поиск + прикрутить удаление. То есть: есть кнопка - она ищет строки. Когда строка найдена, при нажатии другой кнопки - она удаляется. Помогите это как то реализовать.  
Вот код поиска:

```
procedure Form4.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var F:TextFile;
 Str:string; 
 i:integer;
begin
  Assign(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
  reset(F);
while not eof(F) do
   begin
      readln(F, Str);
      if pos(textbox1.text, Str)>0
      then
       textbox2.text:= str;
   end;   
end;
```

---

```
procedure Form5.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
  var
  Base: array of string;
  F: TextFile;
  BaseCount, i: integer;
begin
   AssignFile(F, 'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
   Reset(F);
   BaseCount := 0;
  while not eof(F) do
   begin
    Inc(BaseCount);
    SetLength(Base, BaseCount);
    Readln(F, Base[BaseCount-1]);
   end;
  for i := 0 to BaseCount - 1 do
   begin
      if Pos(textbox1.Text, Base[i-1]) = 0 then
      Writeln(F, Base[i]);
  end;
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: ну правильно, вы же только первую и читаете. Вам нужен цикл, который перебирает строки в файле.  

----  
 
while not eof(F) do  
  begin  
  ...  
  end;

Comment: @teanЫЧ спасибо, помогло :)

Comment: Первую не надо, последнюю не надо. Какую тогда? Из середины?  
Я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Если вам нужно одну строчку вывести в текстбокс, то это то что надо. Если показать нужно все строки, то используйте не TTextBox, a TMemo.  

-----  

И вообще, начните читать учебник. У вас очень много вопросов типа "ничего не понимаю, как делать не знаю, но очень хочется. Объясните мне, сделайте за меня."

Comment: Ну я вижу проблему, а что вы хотите получить в итоге? ТЗ опишите

Comment: @teanЫЧ Начну с начала. У меня есть меню. На нем расположены 4 кнопки. 1 кнопка - выводит форму в которой я при нажатии кнопки добавляю записи в файл. 2 кнопка - выводит форму в которой при нажатии кнопки я вывожу содержимое текстового файла в текстбокс. 3 кнопка - поиск текста(тут проблем нету). И 4 - собственно удаление записей.
Своеобразный телефонный справочник

Comment: Если у вас проблема в пункте 2, то хочу сказать, что само ТЗ кривое. НЕ надо выводить целый файл в текстбокс, для этого есть специализированные компоненты, например TMemo.

Comment: @teanЫЧ прочитал про TMemo. Исходя из прочитанного я понял - TMemo нету в PascalABC.NET. Его заменяет TextBox :) Я решил свою проблему :)

    procedure Form3.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
    var F:textfile;
        s:string;
    begin
    AssignFile(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
    Reset(F);
    while not eof(F) do
     begin
      readln(F, s);
      TextBox1.Text:=TextBox1.Text+s+#13#10
     end; 
     CloseFile(F);
    end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*комментарии закончились*

```
var
  Base: array of string;  // Это наш динамический строковый массив
  F: TextFile;   // это файл
  BaseCount: integer; // это числовая переменная, которая нужная для подсчета количества строк в массиве Base
  i: integer;  // это числовая переменная используемая в цикле
begin
  AssignFile(F, 'nomer.txt');

  Reset(F);
  // устанавливаем BaseCount в 0, ведь массив еще пустой
  BaseCount := 0;  
  // тут начинаем читать каждую строку текстового файла
  while not eof(F) do
  begin
    // увеличиваем BaseCount на 1, ведь одну строку уже прочли
    Inc(BaseCount);
    // увеличиваем размер динамического массива на количество прочитанных строк
    // в итоге получится, что в массиве ровно столько строк сколько в файле
    SetLength(Base, BaseCount);
    // заносим строку из файла в массив
    Readln(F, Base[BaseCount-1]);
  end;

  // переоткрываем файл для записи, стирая его содержимое
  CloseFile(F);
  Rewrite(F);
  // перебираем все строки в массиве
  for i := 0 to BaseCount - 1 do
  begin
    // если строка из массива НЕ содержит строку из текстбокса
    if Pos(ed1.text, Base[i]) = 0 then
      // записываем строку в файл
      Writeln(F, Base[i]);
  end;

  // закрываем файл
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: Только будьте внимательнее. Компилятор не прощает ошибок :)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить __CloseFile(F);__ перед  __Rewrite(F);__

Comment: @teanЫЧ Поставил. Теперь выбивает при нажатии кнопки с такой ошибкой : Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива. У меня было такое когда пытался что то сделать с вашим кодом. Что это значит? И надо ли после CloseFile опять писать AssignFile?

Comment: нет. просто я взял код у товарища @kot-da-vinci, и не посмотрел, что он косячный. я обновил ответ

Comment: @teanЫЧ все отлично работает, спасибо большое за помощь :)
Только вопрос: После того как я удалил нужную строку я решил добавить еще одну. В файл она записалась а при нажатии кнопки - строка не отображается 
Вот код:

    procedure Form3.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
    var F:textfile;
    var a:string;
    begin
    AssignFile(F,'C:\Users\Неизвестен\Desktop\Записная\nomer.txt');
     Reset(F);
     begin
     readln(F, a);
     textbox1.text:= a;
     CloseFile(F);
    end;
    end;

Comment: код должен работать. После __readln(F, a);__ переменная __а__ будет пустой только если файл пустой.  
Проверьте код добавления строки в файл.

Answer (score 2):

Почему не воспользоваться `TStringList`?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    bt1: TButton;
    ed1: TEdit;
    procedure bt1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Base: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.bt1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Base.LoadFromFile('nomer.txt');

  for i := Base.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    if Pos(ed1.Text, Base.Strings[i]) > 0 then
      Base.Delete(i);

  Base.SaveToFile('nomer.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Base.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Base := TStringList.Create;
end;
```

---

Вариант без `StringList`:

```
var
  Base: array of string;
  F: TextFile;
  BaseCount, i: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(F, 'nomer.txt');

  Reset(F);
  BaseCount := 0;
  while not eof(F) do
  begin
    Inc(BaseCount);
    SetLength(Base, BaseCount);
    Readln(F, Base[BaseCount-1]);
  end;

  Rewrite(F);
  for i := 0 to BaseCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Pos(ed1.text, Base[i-1]) = 0 then
      Writeln(F, Base[i]);
  end;

  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: @Sin2p
Добавил вариант без `StringList`.

Comment: @Sin2p, вот тут описание класса TStringList  http://www.delphibasics.ru/TStringList.php  

----  

А так решение, представленное товарищем, вам вполне подходит. И ничего сложного в нем нет. Единственное что в глаза бросается - Base как свойство формы.

Comment: @teanЫЧ Можно было `Base` перенести в глобальные `var`, но мне очень не нравятся глобальные переменные. В больших проектах это обычно ни к чему хорошему не приводит :)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, можно было не выносить Base из метода.

Comment: @teanЫЧ согласен. Можно на каждую операцию (поиск, добавление, удаление) создавать новый экземпляр.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci у меня уже все готово, осталось удаление строк

Comment: от нас то что требуется сейчас? код не работает или не понятно, как работает?

Comment: @teanЫЧ спасибо, я исправлю. Я хотел бы узнать что делает этот код, что за  Basecount и почему именно через него вы удаляет нужные строки

Comment: BaseCount - это счетчик строк. Мы читаем все строки в файле, потом увеличиваем длину строкового массива, заносим строку в массив. Когда весь файл окажется в массиве, начинаем проверять, содержит ли какая-либо строка нужный нам текст. Если строка его НЕ содержит, то она записывается в файл, если СОДЕРЖИТ то не записывается.  

----   

Настоятельно рекомендую почитать какой-нибудь учебник по программированию на Delphi. Тут код элементарный, а вы его уже не понимаете. Что же дальше будет...

Comment: @teanЫЧ дело в том, что я сейчас на практике по паскалю, 2 курс. И мы еще не изучали Delphi.А так как я понимаю что PascalABC.NET - смесь Паскаля + С# + Delphi мне  трудновато т.к если знания С# на начальном уровне и я еще как-то ориентируюсь в нем то в Delphi я - 0. А насчет Basecount'a я не знаю. Из вашего текста я понял так: открывается файл на  чтение. При вводе текста(в моем случае - номер телефона) в текстбокс оно ищет строку в которой есть этот текст. Потом код перезаписывает файл с той информацией которая была в файле но убирая ту строку которая была введена в текстбокс. Я так понимаю